Hairline crack in tub finish
My house was built in 1953 and the tub is original. In the 10 years we’ve lived in this house, we’ve had to have our tub refinished twice.
The first time was because a plumber tried to fix a drain leak with acid and ruined the finish. He paid to have a separate company come in and refinish the tub. But less than a year later, bubbles started to appear in the finish. The company came back and refinished it again, and it’s held up for about 6 years.
But the other day, a new bubble appeared. I didn’t realize it was a bubble - it looked like a small amount of pooled water - but when I went to wipe it away with my toe, the bubble flattened and a hairline crack appeared, which is now about 4” long and growing. I can’t afford to have the tub refinished.
Honestly, I don’t care about aesthetics at this point - eventually we’ll likely have to replace the whole thing - I just want to be able to take a bath without worry. Can I just run a line of caulk on it? Or should I paint a bunch of layers of Porc A Fix on it? Looking for the quick and cheap option, even if it’s ugly.


Without worry... of what? Your tub obviously has issues, and either they're aesthetic or structural. No coating will keep cast iron from coming apart if that's what's happening. What's your goal?

@Jasen superglue doesn't work well with flexure.  At best, the OP could tape over the crack.  It's hard to see what the problem is—a crack in the finish, or a crack in the tub metal.

I was working uner the assumption that this was a surface blemish, but now there's a photo.

@isherwood my goal is to keep the paint crack from getting larger, and to keep water from getting under the finish so that more bubbles don’t form. I’m trying to avoid having to get it refinished a third time.

@Huesmann the crack is in the finish, not in the tub metal.

@Jacquie if you don't care about aesthetics, just tape over it.

@Huesmann what kind of tape would you recommend?

IDK, depends how aesthetics-tolerant you are.
